# Can't send email with PHP Mail

Tags: php

I'm trying to send an email using php. I've the following only it doesn't seem to output anything to my browser nor send my email, can anybody see what i'm doing wrong?

```
    $to = "liam@mysite.co.uk";
$subject = "Alien Sighting";
$message = foreach ($_POST as $key=>$value) {
    $$key = $value;
}
$from = "Sighting@site.co.uk";
$headers = "From:" . $from;
mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
echo "Mail Sent.";
```

Comment: There seems to be a syntax error with your `foreach` structure.

Comment: is this code hosted locally or on some kind of host?

Answer (score 0):

Can you give us $_POST content please ?

Does your PHP configuration display all errors messages? Make sure to use error_reporting (E_ALL) in your dev environnement to find any typo / error. That should help to get an output to your browser.

Answer (score 0):

You have to be sure to setup your SMTP server to send your email if you are running the script on your computer otherwise you can get a test server so you don't have to setup the SMTP it will send automatically

Answer (score 0):

Are u using Rmail.php? Do u uploaded your code to a webserver or is it on your local PC?

I am always using Rmail.php to send mails.

```
$mail = new Rmail();
$mail->setFrom(YOUR ADDRESS);
$mail->setSubject(YOUR SUBJECT);
$mail->setHTML($textSchueler);
$mail->send(array($address));
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll also want to check and make sure your server is configured to send email at all. While most shared hosting accounts will be configured for you if you are setting up your own server or developing locally PHP may not have the any way to send the messages. Try checking to see if the mail() function returns true indicating the message was successfully sent and then look in the mail logs on the server to verify transmission.

Answer (score 0):

In this kind of situation where PHP does not output anything to your browser (even it should), most likely the script fails before your `echo` statement.

Make sure you have not disabled error reporting. See PHP [runtime configuration](http://php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php) `error_reporting` and `display_errors`. You can change error reporting behaviour also runtime with [error_reporting()](http://php.net/manual/es/function.error-reporting.php) function in the code. Enabling error reporting helps you to figure out what the problem might be.

Even you had disabled the error reporting on the browser, check out your webserver logs. They should have details what's the problem (syntax error in the script, failed mail delivery by mail function call... there are many possibilities).